# Pass List/ Array to stored procedure and retrieve parameters one by one in stored procedure.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have Drop Down List with check box in my asp.net page.
in that page i am going to checked multiple / single / all values.

now i want to pass all selected values from dropdownlist to sql server 2005 stored procedure as parameters.

i want to Pass the array of selected values as a string, each array item separated by a ','

And in stored procedure i want to retrieve each values one by one. 
(using split function or any better option ? )

and i want to process insert query on each selected parameters.

any help please.

I have tried This Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_LIST] 
@ID_LIST VARCHAR(200)
```

AS
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @ID_LIST, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@ID_LIST) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE 
    (ID)
     VALUES (convert(int, substring(@ID_LIST, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
  SELECT @pos = @nextpos
```

END
   RETURN
END

BUT IS THIS CORRECT ??

I GOT ERROR.

please note this > one by one i want to retrieve parameters and at each time i have insert query.

Comment: Are you asking for help on the C# side to concatenate the values?  Or the SQL side to split them back out?  Since you are in SQL 2005 this or XML parameters are your only options, in newer SQL Server versions you can also use Table Valued parameters (although upgrading SQL Server is usually never a simple option for applications already in production).

Comment: Most folks I know have, at one point or other, written some form of `dbo.Split` UDF that takes a string and a delimiter, and rips it into a single-column table result... I suggest this is no different. It is annoying that SQL Server lacks an inbuilt "split" function, yes.

Comment: I have edited my question please refer that again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS ANSWER OF MY QUESTION, 
YOU PLEASE CHANGE YOUR STORED PROCEDURE 
AS SHOWN BELOW.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE SplitList
@List varchar(500) --list like 1,12,13 or john,12,bobe
```

AS
BEGIN

```
DECLARE @value varchar(10), @Pos int

SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))+ ','
SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)

IF REPLACE(@List, ',', '') <> ''
BEGIN
    WHILE @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @value = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@List, @Pos - 1)))
        IF @value <> ''
        BEGIN
            -- put your code here 
        END
        SET @List = RIGHT(@List, LEN(@List) - @Pos)
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)

    END
END
```

END

THANKS TO ALL.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings (this is also called a 'tally table') with c# and then split them in sql.

A good article about how to split 'tally table': http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/